# How do I get multiple applications to SAML Single Sign On to one application?

Tags: saml, identityserver4, federated-identity

Looking for direction.

I've got a single web application that I want to SSO into from multiple applications that all handle their own authentication. The web application wants to use SAML for SSO'ing. The web application requires IdP metadata (we've got one web service that is its own IdP, don't know what the other applications are using). The web application can also accept SAML Assertions with provisions to determine user access when it creates the new users after they SSO in.

I'm looking to get a one stop shop for the web application to hit to determine authentication and authorization.

I've got another web application (.NET Core) that runs Identity Server 4 to handle authentication for one of the many applications that wants to SSO into the web application. Can I use that? I would need to integrate SAML into it. How do I do that? Also, how can I easily integrate all the other applications to use this one web application to SSO into the SAML web application. Is this what Federating is?

Trying to do this with minimal work to all the other applications because that kind of integration work across multiple teams would be kind of a nightmare.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using Identity Server 4, you're probably best to stick with it and add SAML SSO support to it.

SAML SSO support isn't included natively in Identity Server 4 but there are two commercial offerings that add this support.

The following link has some good articles describing how to support SAML SSO in Identity Server 4.

https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/tagged/identityserver4